# Determining where to animate the map given a list of GeoPoints

Tags: android, android-mapview, zooming

My android application loads some markers on an overlay onto a MapView.
The markers are placed based on a dynamic list of GeoPoints.
I want to move the map center and zoom into the area with most items.
Naively, I can calculate the superposition of all the points, but I would like to remove the points that are very far from the mass of points from the calculation.
Is there a known way to calculate this ? (e.g. probability, statistics .. ?)

Answer (score 1):

I once solved the exact same problem you describe for a real estate app I wrote a little while ago.  What worked for me was:

- Calculate a center point somehow
  (centroid, average the lats and
  lons, or whatever)
- Calc the distances between this imaginary point and each of your real pins
- Use a Standard Deviation algorithm and remove any pin whose distance has a StdDev >
  2 (or whatever threshold for you)
- Repeat steps 1 - 3 (you'll be using a new center point each time
  you loop) until there are no more
  outliers to remove at step 3

This approach work great for my needs.  But I'm sure there's more interesting ways to solve the same problem if you look around.  For example, I found this interesting CompSci paper...

http://people.scs.carleton.ca/~michiel/outliers.pdf

Good luck!